# How do I ensure index on first element of an array in MongoDB for faster querying?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

Ensuring an index on a element of an array does not work as expected for me.

E.g. with the following data

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 7891236423, "arr" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : 7891236424, "arr" : [ "b", "c", "d" ] }
{ "_id" : 7891236425, "arr" : [ "b", "c", "a" ] }
>
```

the following query works as expected when there is no index

```
> db.test.find({"arr.0":"a"})
{ "_id" : 7891236423, "arr" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
>
```

but the same query does not return a result if I try to create an index on `arr.0`

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({"arr.0":1})
> db.test.find({"arr.0":"a"})
>
```

I do not understand what is happening here, in my opinion an index should never have an effect on the returned data. Or should it?

Is this a bug? Or index abuse? I'd be happy for any explanations for this behavior, and even happier for any hints how I can achieve an index on a single array element.

PS: I know that I can create an index on `arr` and query `arr` first before querying `arr.0`, which is a valid workaround for the given example. But this does not help as soon as I need to sort a huge amount of data by `arr.0` (MongoDB demands an index for this)

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: We were able to reproduce this problem using 1.8.5, but it seems to work in 2.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with the v0 indexes used in 1.8 and prior.  The new v1 indexes in 2.0+ support this.  Upgrading to 2.0.3 should solve your problem.  You can find instructions on upgrading to 2.0 here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-Upgrading

Comment: stbrody, thanks a lot, upgrading to 2.0.3 did the trick :) I had to explicitely dropIndex and ensureIndex again, then everything worked as expected.